# angular-cli different versions in the same computer

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working with Angular2 in several projects. Each of this projects uses a different version of `angular-cli`, so, I need to be able to run and compile for production each separately with the correct version of `angular-cli`. When I installed `angular-cli` locally using `save-dev`, ng commands not found so I cannot create a build distribution for the project.

So the question are, how can I have multiples `angular-cli` version in the same machine, without installed globally (with -g option)?, it is possible run ng commands without installing `angular-cli` globally?

Comment: Detailed working solution for existing angular projects given. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195249/3037341)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which is a Node Version Manager and allows you to work with different global modules in each Node version.

In my case, I'm working with Node 6.9.5 and Angular2 in one project, and Node 10 and Angular6 in other.

You only have to pay attention which version is seated and work as normally as you do.

Comment: Can you provide the links how we can install two angular cli(s) using NVM. And also how to switch between node versions?

Comment: Sorry my late response, here you have https://github.com/creationix/nvm.

Comment: How does this relate to different versions of Angular? This is for different versions of Node, right?

Answer (score 62):

You should always be able to run local for your current directory version of *ANGULAR CLI* by running:

```
node_modules/.bin/ng <ANY NG COMMAND>
```

instead of just

```
ng <ANY NG COMMAND>
```

just make sure, you are running this command from the root directory where your main *package.json* is located (and its *node_modules* directory)

There is an `npm` command returning `node_modules/.bin` path (which may be used for shorter writing):

```
// does not work on Windows   
`npm bin`/ng <ANY NG COMMAND>
```

Note that back ticks are used around `npm bin` and not single quote sign.

`ng` command is also added to `package.json` `scripts` section, so it is also possible to run local copy like this:

```
npm run ng -- <NG_OPTIONS>
```

note `--` flag terminator, it must be inserted before ng options.

If you want to create a new ng project using particular version but without installing `@angular/cli` globally, you can use [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) command:

```
npx @angular/cli@7 new <APP_NAME>
```

here `npx` will ***temporary*** install `@angular/cli` with latest (@7 at the time of answering :)) version and run its `ng` executable with passed parameters.

You even can do something completely useless (because local copy of `@angular/cli` was installed with `ng new`). Run `ng serve` with @6 version of CLI on @7 new project:

```
cd <APP_NAME>
npx @angular/cli@6 serve
```

***UPDATE***

Running these commands will use `ng` executable located locally within `node_modules/.bin/`, so you do not need to have it installed globally:

```
cd <APP_NAME>
npx ng serve
```

Comment: thanks for response, i never do this like you say. Instead of, i figure it out how. In your current working project you are free to use the version of angular-cli you need, if you install angular-cli globally (- g option), when you create a build distribution (ng build --prod), it use the local version instead of the globally. In that way you always has the latest version installed on your computer and can run commands from ng without be inside on local bin folder. I will mark the question as finish

Thanks for the response!!!

Comment: The comment above did not work for me - but the answer worked i.e node_modules/.bin/ng <ANY NG COMMAND>

Comment: Did this answer depend on certain things (say the cli), being installed as "dev" vs "global"? Which one(s)?

Comment: The question was about running ng commands on different angular cli projects, without installing angular cli globally. Actually, after creating a new angular cli app, it should be already installed and added to package.json as dev dependency (because it runs nam install). If for some reason you need to install angular cli for particular app, then run it as npm I @angular/cli -D

Answer (score 33):

In case someone else came here like me with the same problem, I found this method as the easiest. I had `@angular/cli@1.7.3` installed globally as I have an ongoing project created from that version(angular 5.0 roughly) but wanted to install `@angular/cli@6.0.0`.
What I did was installing [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) and then created the project using `npx`

Install `npx` frpm `npm`

```
npm install -g npx
```

Create new project with the desired cli version. Use `@angular/cli@latest` or just `@angular/cli` for the latest version.

```
npx -p @angular/cli@6.0.0 ng new my-project
```

Inside the project root folder, execute `ng --version` to see the version of you cli. But I recommend you use `npx` prefix to every command that uses `ng` as follows.

```
npx ng --version

npx ng generate component my-component
```

Here the `npx` look for the `ng` command exists locally in `./node_modules/.bin/` directory and executes it.

Comment: Thank you so much. The only small difference is that using `-v` didn't work for me, I had to use `--version`.

Comment: here is the solution. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

create a Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.1
```

build this docker image

```
docker build . -t angular/ng6.1.1
```

run the docker image build in the last step

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app angular/ng6.1.1 ng new hello-angular
```

You will find hello-angular project was created in your local folder, and if you want to 
use different angular version, change the angular/cli version in docker file and build a 
new docker image to create a new angular project.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

a. You have one angular version installed and working on your machine. and now you want to install a different angular version.

b. You have installed the Angular CLI globally for the current angular project.

c. You are using Ubuntu/Linux.

Few Important comands:

```
$ node -v
$ npm -v
$ ng v
```

1. Install NVM:

   i. Before installing nvm, run this in terminal: `touch ~/.bash_profile`

   ```
   Add following lines in  ~/.bashrc file

   sudo vim  ~/.bashrc

   source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
   export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   ```

   ii. After, run this in terminal:

   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash`

   iii. Do not forget to Restart your terminal OR use the command `$source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` (this will refresh the available commands in your system path).

   iv. In the terminal, use command `$nvm --version` and you should see the version

   v. Now install specific node Version

   `e.g. new/angular-repo/path$ nvm install 13.11.0`

   vi. To check list of node versions installed using:

   `new/angular-repo/path$ nvm list`

   vii. To use specific node for current project use:

   `new/angular-repo/path$ nvm use v13.11.0`
2. Install specific Angular CLI

   `new/angular-repo/path$ npm install @angular/cli@7.2.4`
3. To install all dependencies run following command:

   `new/angular-repo/path$ npm install`

   After completion of the above command. make sure Node, Angular CLI, NPM, Angular have the intended version.

   `new/angular-repo/path$ ng v`
4. If npm version is not showing as per your requirement in the above command, then install specific version using the following command

   `new/angular-repo/path$ npm install npm@version`

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the following:

1. Create a new folder and instantiate a node project with `npm init`.
2. Install the Angular-CLI that related to the version that you need.
3. Remove `package.json` file.
4. Create/Import an Angular project that will have the version related to the CLI.

[Further reading and explanation here](https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-install-a-specific-angular-version-16d4766341f3)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solutions is using `npx`.

Solution:

1. Install npx, type on terminal: `npm install -g npx`
2. Create a new angular project typing: `npx -p @angular/cli@VERSION_YOU_WANT_TO_USE ng new PROJECT_NAME`