# How do i install two versions of angular in my system

Tags: angular

For each project I use different version of angular-cli. So I need to manage two or more angular-cli version in one system. How can I install those?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli different versions in the same computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018777/angular-cli-different-versions-in-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Use local version of @angular/cli instead of global version.

Global Version - npm install -g @angular/cli
Local Version - npm install @angular/cli

For both the project install the angular version locally in the project.