# running Angular 4 application with angular-cli 8

Tags: angular

I have to be able to run a legacy application written with Angular 4. But when I execute `ng serve`, I get the error `The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.`

My Angular CLI version is 8.2.2 and I have Node 10.16. I guess I cannot run an old Angular application with this version of Angular CLI, can I ?

yet the project package.json is referencing "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3", and I've installed all the packages with `npm i`.

I noticed the project is missing an angular.json file but as far as I remember, Angular 4 did not use this kind of file.

any idea ?

Comment: have you seen this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018777/angular-cli-different-versions-in-the-same-computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ng serve` directly on the command line, it will use your globally installed Angular version which is `8.2.2`. To use the local version you could either use the `npx` command:

`npx ng serve`

This will use the angular cli found in the local project.

Or you could use an npm script in your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
}
```

then you can use `npm run start`.