# Unable to start downloaded angular project

Tags: angular

I've downloaded a project from a friend and when I start the project using `ng serve`... It gives me error saying

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

I'm pretty sure I am in the root folder. I also tried several commands I found on my hours of searching such as.. updating, uninstalling, and re-installing angular/cli... I've also tried `npm update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=9.1.8`, but nothing seems to work.

**Note :** this project runs on `localhost:4200`

Btw, I have another angular project that also runs on `4200` and it runs successfully using `ng serve`.
Does this have to do on why I am not able to run the downloaded angular project?

Comment: Have both the projects on same angular version? also try clearing cache using the command `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: @PardeepJain I just noticed, they have different angular versions. I already tried `npm cache clean -f` but no still no luck.

Comment: okay, might be the case you need to install different angular CLI as per the angular versions of your projects.
also, you can use `nvm` to handle different versions on a same machine.

Comment: @PardeepJain I'm sorry but can you provide ang example :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43018777/5043867
might  help you out .